# Problems run SwaggerUI - Java (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, rest, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

I have an application made in JAX-RS that is running perfectly, and that contains only one REST call of the GET type.

I implemented Swagger in this app, using OpenAPI, and when I open json, it shows the information successfully:

http://localhost:9080/fcrs-srv-historico/v0/openapi.json

[image: OPENAPI.JSON]

My problem is that I am not able to open the visual layer of Swagger UI.

I don't know if I'm putting the wrong URL or if my project is missing some configuration.

I tried the following URLs:

http://localhost:9080/fcrs-srv-historico/doc/index.html

http://localhost:9080/fcrs-srv-historico/v0/doc/index.html

http://localhost:9080/fcrs-srv-historico/v0/index.html

http://localhost:9080/fcrs-srv-historico/doc/

Folow the Code:

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
package br.com.bradesco.historico.config;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.filters.CORSFilter;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.log.TechLoggerProducer;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.resources.rest.HistoricResource;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.services.HistoricJsonProducer;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.services.HistoricRules;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.utils.DateUtils;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;


@ApplicationPath("/v0")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        BeanConfig conf = new BeanConfig();
        conf.setTitle("Histórico de Conversa");
        conf.setDescription("Obtém histórico de conversa do chat corporativo");
        conf.setVersion("1.0.0");
        conf.setHost("localhost:9080");
        conf.setBasePath("/fcrs-srv-historico/v0");
        conf.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
        conf.setResourcePackage("br.com.bradesco.historico");
        conf.setScan(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(CORSFilter.class);
        resources.add(HistoricResource.class);
        resources.add(CustomOpenApiResourceConfig.class);
        resources.add(PropertiesManipulator.class);
        resources.add(TechLoggerProducer.class);
        resources.add(HistoricJsonProducer.class);
        resources.add(HistoricRules.class);
        resources.add(DateUtils.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

**CustomOpenApiResourceConfig.java**

```
package br.com.bradesco.historico.config;

import io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.integration.SwaggerConfiguration;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

public class CustomOpenApiResourceConfig extends OpenApiResource {

  private String servers = "http://127.0.0.1:9080/fcrs-srv-historico/v0";

  @Override
  public Response getOpenApi(HttpHeaders headers, UriInfo uriInfo, String type)
      throws Exception {
    setOpenApiConfiguration(getConfiguration());
    return super.getOpenApi(headers, uriInfo, type);
  }

  private SwaggerConfiguration getConfiguration() {
    final SwaggerConfiguration configuration = new SwaggerConfiguration();
    configuration.setOpenAPI(getOpenApi());
    return configuration;
  }

  private OpenAPI getOpenApi() {
    final OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPI();
    openAPI.setInfo(getApiInfo());
    openAPI.servers(getServers());
    return openAPI;
  }

  private Info getApiInfo() {
    final Info info = new Info();
    info.setTitle("fcrs-srv-historico");
    info.setDescription("API de histórico d chat corporativo.");
    info.setVersion("v0");
    return info;
  }

  private List<Server> getServers() {
    return Arrays.asList(servers.split(",")).stream().map(srv -> {
      Server server = new Server();
      server.url(srv);
      return server;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

**HistoricResource.java**

```
package br.com.bradesco.historico.resources.rest;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.services.HistoricRules;
import br.com.bradesco.historico.services.Histories;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
/**
 * Controller class, responsible for controlling the search for history in the api.
 *
 */
@Path("/")
@Api(value = "Histórico")
@ApplicationScoped
public class HistoricResource {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    @Histories
    JsonObject historiesObj;

    public HistoricResource() {
        super();
    }

    HistoricRules historicRules = new HistoricRules();
    
    /**
     * Gets the customer's conversation history according to the userId and Index passed.
     * 
     * @param userId - userid
     * @param index - index
     * @return Output of a JSON containing the last 20 messages that are in the history, depending on the Index.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Buscar histórico")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = HistoricResource.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "Nenhum conteúdo") })
    @Path("getConversationHistory/userId/{userId}/index/{index}")
    public Response getConversationHistory(@PathParam("userId") String userId, @PathParam("index") int index) {
        JsonObject historicByUserId = null;
        JsonArray historic = null;
        

        try {
            historicByUserId = historiesObj.getJsonObject(userId);
            historic = historicByUserId.getJsonArray("messages");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("History not found - STATUS[" + Status.NOT_FOUND + "]");
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        
        String last20HistoricalMessages = historicRules.getLast20HistoricalMessages(historic, historicByUserId, index);
        
        if(last20HistoricalMessages.contentEquals("INDEX_OUT_OF_RANGE")) {
            logger.info("The index received is out of range - STATUS[" + Status.BAD_REQUEST + "]");
            return Response.ok().status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        
        String oldestDateOfMessage = String.valueOf(historicRules.getOldestDateJson(historic, index, last20HistoricalMessages));

        if (last20HistoricalMessages.equals("EMPTY")) {
            logger.info("History is empty - STATUS[" + Status.CREATED + "]");
            return Response.ok(historicRules.getHistoricEmpty()).status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

        } else if (historicRules.isHistoricOutOfPeriodAllowed(oldestDateOfMessage)) {
            logger.info("History period longer than allowed - STATUS[" + Status.BAD_REQUEST + "], isEndMessaByPeriod[" + historicRules.isEndMessaByPeriod() + "]");
            return Response.ok(
                    historicRules.getHistoricOutdated(historicRules.isEndMessage(), historicRules.isEndMessaByPeriod()))
                    .status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        String last20HistoricalMessagesFormated = historicRules.addEndMessageToHistory(
                last20HistoricalMessages.toString(), historicRules.isEndMessage(), historicRules.isEndMessaByPeriod());
        
        logger.info("History found - STATUS[" + Status.CREATED + "]");
        return Response.ok(last20HistoricalMessagesFormated).status(Status.CREATED).build();
    }

}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>
      html
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      *,
      *:before,
      *:after
      {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      body
      {
        margin:0;
        background: #fafafa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "/fcrs-srv-historico/v0/openapi.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
      });
      // End Swagger UI call region

      window.ui = ui;
    };
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this can help you but if your openapi.json work correctly u can try modify your **index.html** like a this.. (check url)

```html
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script>
    var protocol = window.location.protocol;
    var host = window.location.host;    
    var urlPattern = protocol +  "//" + host + "/fcrs-srv-historico/swagger"; 
    var urlHost = protocol +  "//" + host;
    
    function loadScript(scriptPath) {   
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = function (){
            var functionUrl = urlPattern + scriptPath;
        }
        script.setAttribute('src', urlPattern + scriptPath);
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="url/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="url/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>
      html
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      *,
      *:before,
      *:after
      {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      body
      {
        margin:0;
        background: #fafafa;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script>
        loadScript('/swagger-ui-bundle.js');
        loadScript('/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js');
        
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = urlPattern + "/swagger-ui.css";
        head.appendChild(link);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div> 
    <script>  
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: urlHost + "/fcrs-srv-historico/v0/openapi.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
      })
      // End Swagger UI call region

      window.ui = ui
    }
  </script>
  
  <script>
    document.querySelector("link[href='url/favicon-32x32.png']").href = urlPattern + "/favicon-32x32.png";
    document.querySelector("link[href='url/favicon-16x16.png']").href = urlPattern + "/favicon-16x16.png";
  </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

for use /swagger here

```js
var urlPattern = protocol +  "//" + host + "/fcrs-srv-historico/swagger";
```

you need build your war with swagger resource.. Add in your .pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                ....
                <webResources>
                    ...
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/doc</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>/swagger</targetPath>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```